# c# linq select new class Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i want to bind gridview with my custom entity whitch i populate from data base
but i get error 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
i know the error is from my **gridlink** class
when select new and want to set to *link* property 
in this line : `link = { linkName = "tyr", linkSrc = "ytr" },`
because  when i earase it the error stop and gridview bind 
thanks

```
  public class gridcolumns
{

    public decimal cost { get; set; }
    public Int32 count { get; set; }
    public gridlink link { get; set; }

    public gridcolumns()
    {

        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }
}

public class gridlink
{
    public string linkName { get; set; }
    public string linkSrc { get; set; }

    public gridlink()
    {

    }
}
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Data281DataContextDataContext conx = new Data281DataContextDataContext();
    List<tbl_2_CheckReqNo_NotValid> allresult = conx.tbl_2_CheckReqNo_NotValids.ToList();
    gridcolumns lastMantWithDate = new gridcolumns();
    if (Request.QueryString.Count == 0)
    {
        var lastMantWithDaste = from pe in allresult //where allresult != null
                                orderby Convert.ToDecimal(pe.mandeh) descending
                                group pe by pe.mant into grouped
                                where grouped != null
                                select new gridcolumns
                                {
                                    link = { linkName = "tyr", linkSrc = "ytr" },
                                    cost = grouped.Sum(g => Convert.ToDecimal(g.mandeh)),
                                    count = grouped.Count(),

                                };

        GrdOstan.DataSource = lastMantWithDaste;
        GrdOstan.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: What are the types of `pe.mandeh` and `pe.mant`?

Comment: are you shure, that this even compiles? i believe that  `link = { linkName = "tyr", linkSrc = "ytr" },` should throw an error ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be instantiating a `gridlink` like this:

```
link = new gridlink { linkName = "tyr", linkSrc = "ytr" },
```

Consider that for each item your query produces you create a `gridcolumns` object. The `link` property of that object is initially `null`; you should set it to `new gridlink` before trying to use it at all.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need

```
link = new gridLink { linkName = "tyr", linkSrc = "ytr" }
```

instead of

```
link = { linkName = "tyr", linkSrc = "ytr" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
select new gridcolumns
           {
           link = { linkName = "tyr", linkSrc = "ytr" },
```

With:

```
select new gridcolumns
           {
           link = new gridlink  { linkName = "tyr", linkSrc = "ytr" },
```

You need to instantiate a new object of type `gridLink` using the `new` keyword

Answer (score 0):

In your line:

```
link = { linkName = "tyr", linkSrc = "ytr" }
```

You need "new gridlink", like this:

```
link = new gridlink { linkName = "tyr", linkSrc = "ytr" }
```

Personally, I think it's unfortunate that your code compiled.  If I tried:

```
List<gridlink> links = new List<gridlink>();
links.Add({ linkName = "tyr", linkSrc = "ytr" });
```

I would correctly get a bevy of syntax errors.

Adding `new gridlink` should resolve this problem.